# HTML >> Very simple question

Tags: html, entities

Hey ppl, can someone tell me the &#num; for that >> sign. The one where the >> are one character. Thanks :)

Bonus points for << aswell ^_^

Comment: Note that these are quotation marks, and shouldn't be used as Unicode-art. They are not arrows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« and » are `&#171; and &#187;`

Also see wikipedia for more

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: or, if you prefer to use the entity names: &raquo; and &laquo;

Answer (score 2):

This is `&#171;` and `&#187;`. You can use the "translate" feature provided by many HTML editors (I used BBEdit).

Answer (score 1):

`&laquo;` and `&raquo;`